# VB6 ActiveX controls into a TCL/Tk application

Tags: vb6, activex, tcl, tk-toolkit

Whats the most common way of instantiating VB6 ActiveX controls inside of an Tcl/Tk wrapper application.

Are there performance issues with this setup i.e. around GDI handles?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there with VB6 **and** Tcl/Tk, but it sounds scary.

Comment: @Tiberiu why scary? is there a preference for an alternative language when building the ActiveX controls assuming the decision for Tcl/Tk is fixed?

Comment: It sounds like a valid question from 10 years ago. :-)
Nowadays VB6 is outright deprecated and Tcl is (unfortunatelly?) rather marginalized. I can see doing something cross-platform in Tcl/Tk, but then you wouldn't tie it down with ActiveX and an unsupported runtime.

Comment: The OP probably has existing ActiveX controls written in VB6.  Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Download the ActiveTcl distribution](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads/) and install it.
2. Referring to [The TclTk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1884) [Download the tcom library for tcl](http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/)
3. The tcom README instructs to copy the tcom folder found in the \lib folder from zip file into C:\Tcl\lib to install the tcom library.

Now create a text file with the .tcl extension containing the following:

```
# This demo of calling the Fire method on the MyControl VB6 ActiveX control
puts "Hello World";
package require tcom;
set myinstance [::tcom::ref createobject "MyKit.MyControl"];
$myinstance Fire;
```

Double click the .tcl file to open it using wish.

Another option is to use "Open Tcl" a.k.a. optcl which apparently unlike tcom supports embedding a visual ActiveX component in a Tk based application. The install is similar to tcom (copy the optcl folder into the C:\tcl\lib folder.

Here is the optcl version of the code:

```
#load optcl
package require optcl
set myinstance [optcl::new MyKit.MyControl];
$myinstance Fire;
```